# WPF list binding fails

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've followed the instruction from [here](https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2015/windows-xaml-tips-resourcedictionary-with-codebehind). Nevertheless my binding seems to fail for I have no result in my window. What I want to do is simply to bind a list if items to ListView.
XAML file content:

```
<Window x:Class="IV_sem___PwSG___WPF_task1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IV_sem___PwSG___WPF_task1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800"
    MinHeight="500" MinWidth="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="5" Background="Aqua">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                       FontSize="18" FontFamily="Arial"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                       FontSize="14" FontFamily="Arial"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"
                       FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"></TextBlock>
            <Button Content="Add to cart" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<!--<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindow />
</Window.DataContext>-->

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Load"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="ExitMenuItem_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Products">
            <MenuItem Header="Add products" Click="AddProductMenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Clear products"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="About" Click="AboutMenuItem_Click"/>
    </Menu>

    <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Shop">
            <!--<Grid>-->
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"/>
            <!--</Grid>-->
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Warehouse">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

.cs file content:

```
namespace IV_sem___PwSG___WPF_task1{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Item> itemList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        itemList = new List<Item>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AboutMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is simple shop manager.", "About application", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

    private void ExitMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public class Item
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
        Category Category { get; set; }
        double Price { get; set; }
        public Item(string a, string b, Category c, double d)
        {
            Name = a; Description = b; Category = c; Price = d;
        }

    }

    private void AddProductMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemList.Add(new Item("Computer", "Computer's description", Category.Electronics, 2499.99));
        itemList.Add(new Item("Apple", "Apple's description", Category.Food, 1.99));
        itemList.Add(new Item("Computer", "Computer's description", Category.Electronics, 2499.99));
    }
}

public enum Category
{
    Electronics, Food
}
}
```

Category is an enum type.
List is a property of MainWindow class.
It should be working according to the link above.

Comment: You bind to a property "itemList" of whatever object is in the DataContext. Where is itemList? Does it exist? What is the DataContext? Or in other words: Does the binding source for your ListView.ItemsSource binding actually exist?

Comment: @elgonzo itemList is initialized in `MainWindow()` constructor and it is filled with some elements. DataContext is for sure the namespace that contains `MainWindow` class as it's been the only namespace in my project so far. I tried assigning `itemList` to `this.DataContext` in .cs and using only `"{Binding}"` instead of `"{Binding itemList}"` in XAML - this made no difference anyway. Shuould I give you some more code?

Comment: Yes please. Show what collection type the itemList is, where and how you fill it, and where/how you set the DataContext for your window. Expand your question with this information (do not try to explain it here in the comments...)

Comment: Did i overlook it, but where do you set the DataContext for your window? I see it being commented out in the XAML...

Comment: @elgonzo setting `DataContext` the way it was (the piece I've commented out) caused compilation failure near `InitializeComponent()` in `MainWindow()` constructor - setting `DataContext` at the XAML beggining, the way you adviced, worked.

Comment: Even if it would compile successfully, it would not have worked that way ;). First, you would have created an infinite recursion, leading to a (Ta-da!) stack overflow. MainWindow would create another MainWindow object as its DataContext. This other MainWindow would yet again create another MainWindow object as its DataContext... rinse and repeat. But even if you would have fixed the infinite recursion somehow, it would still not have worked. Because the MainWindow object you would have created as DataContext would not have been the same object as your real/primary MainWindows...

Comment: Well, it seems I don't get well all those bindings and DataContexts yet...It all is extremely intricate

Comment: The problem scenario i just outlined has nothing to do with bindings or data context. Your confusion is probably due to not being accustomed to the (somewhat ugly, i admit) XAML syntax yet. When this part `<local:MainWindow/>` of the XAML is eventually evaluated by your program to render the UI, it instructs your program to **create** a MainWindow object (i.e. `new MainWindow();`). Like `<Button/>` would instruct your program to create a Button object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question has three problems.

**1. The ListView.ItemsSource binding**

The program does not set the DataContext for the ListView or one of its parent containers. So the binding in `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" ... />` cannot be resolved.

Since *itemList* is a property of the MainWindow itself, as a quick fix i suggest to bind the MainWindow DataContext to the MainWindow itself:

```
<Window x:Class="IV_sem___PwSG___WPF_task1.MainWindow"
    ...
    ...
    x:Name="Self"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Self}"
>
```

**2. The itemList**

*itemList* is just a simple `List<T>` collection. `List<T>` does not have a built-in mechanism to inform the ListView and the binding engine whenever items have been added to or removed from the list. When the program adds items to the *itemList* in the AddProductMenuItem_Click handler, the ListView will not update, simply because it is not being notified that the *itemList* has been changed.

The fix is rather simple: Use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`. ObservableCollection provides notifications about item addition and removal. These notifications are being understood by WPF and enable the ListView to refresh its view whenever the collection has been altered.

**3. The Item class**

The *itemList* collection contains `Item` objects. UI elements in the item template used by the ListView bind to properties of these `Item` objects. However, the properties of the `Item` class are not public. The binding to these properties fails if they are not public.

The fix, again, is rather straightforward: Make all properties participating in bindings public.

Comment: "i suggest to bind the MainWindow DataContext to the MainWindow itself" - isn't it like MainWindow's DataContext is by default set to itself?

Comment: Now bindings inside my DataTemplate seem not to wrok, as I have only a button in each element on my ListView

Comment: Properties were not public! That was the issue... Now it seems to be working.

Comment: With regard to DataContext: The DataContext has no value by default (it is null). The quick fix i proposed in my answer (binding DataContext to a UI element) is something you would do only rarely in WPF. As the name "data context" implies, you would set DataContext normally to an object that offers the data which the respective UI element(s) are concerned with (both in terms of presentation+interaction). Normally, UI elements are not the data itself, so it would not really make sense to have DataContext by default point to the UI element it is a member of.

Comment: With regard to the non-public properties: You are right. I completely missed that the properties in the Item class were not being public. I will complete my answer in a moment. Sorry for not spotting it earlier...

Comment: Some additional note with regard to DataContext: DataContext - as well as other properties of WPF UI elements - are not ordinary properties. They are what WPF calls "dependency properties". One aspect of dependency properties is that they *can* inherit the value from the same property of its parent container/UI element. DataContext is such a DP exhibiting this behavior. Note that the DataContext has been set for the MainWindow UI element. The DataContext property of the ListView (lets ignore the item template for now) has not been set at all, still the binding has no trouble resolving. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) How is that possible? Does the binding  for ListView ItemsSource access the DataContext property of the MainWindow. No. The binding only accesses the DataContext property of the ListView. But nobody did set the DataContext property of the ListView. However, since DataContext is an inheriting dependency property, it inherits the DataContext from its parent container (TabItem/TabControl). This parent container DataContext again inherits from its parent DataContext... and so on, until the inheritance chain finally reaches the MainWindow where the DataContext has been set explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Use Observable collection instead of List as below

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> itemList { get; set; }
```

because Observable Collection implemented using INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged it's notify collection change event and update UI.